# displaying a commenting form with the on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please am trying to create a scenario where by if a user clicks on a link called comment to comment on a post, a commenting form will appear for him to be able to comment only on that post. this is the function i created but its not working.

```
function comment() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        $('#commentForm').show();
        return false;
    });
};
```

I impemented the function on the link like this.

```
<a href"#" onClick"comment()">comment</a>
```

The same link is meant to show up under every retrieved post result please help.

Comment: Is it possible that your problem is a missing equal sign?   onClick="comment()"

Comment: twasnt the equal sign, used the tutorial by jakeclarkson but it only triggers the appearance of the first form. the others don't show and every other link carrying the commentLink class triggers the first form only

Comment: It's unclear whether you want a different instance of the comment form for each post or if you want to reuse the same comment form for all posts.  If you want a different instance of the comment form, then you will need to have different copies of the form with different `id` attributes so that your links know which form to display.

Answer (score 3):

I would give all of your `<a>` elements a class, say `"commentLink"`, and then attach the `click` event handler solely via jQuery. This will save you having to put in all the `onclick=""` inline JavaScript, e.g.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="commentLink">comment one</a>
<a href="#" class="commentLink">comment two</a>
<a href="#" class="commentLink">comment three</a>
<a href="#" class="commentLink">comment four</a>
```

**JS**

```
$(".commentLink").click(function () {
    $("#commentForm").show();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: When compared to other solutions this is the simplest solution. Ofcourse there is a typo in onClick"comment()"

Comment: It worked but it only triggers the appearance of the first form. the others don't show and every other link carrying the commentLink class triggers the first form only.

Comment: Should it be showing `#commentForm` every time or is the form different for each element?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
function comment() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        $('#commentForm').show();
        return false;
    });
};

<a href"#" onClick="comment()">comment</a>
```

To this:

```
function comment() { //EDIT- you don't need an arg
    $('#commentForm').show();
    return false;
};

<a href"#" onClick="comment()">comment</a>
```

You can also try this:

```
$('a:contains("comment")').click(function comment() {
    $('#commentForm').show();
    return false;
});

<a href"#">comment</a>
```

Comment: Don't you need onClick="comment(this)" too? Or did I miss something?

Comment: still giving the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might have many hidden comment forms with the same name. Can that be the case? If you name them differently and specify which form to display, that might solve it, no?

Comment: but am getting results from a database and want to display the posts so that others can comment, the field carrying the comment link is continues to display under each post for commenting. or could there be a better way to do that? i use php and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You missed = sign , It should be like below

```
<a href"#" onClick="comment()">comment</a>
```